# Why is the MetaTable not picking up some association columns?

Tags: asp.net-4.0, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a fairly complex web form using DynamicData with a bunch of customized FieldTemplates.  Everything worked fine under .NET 3.5 SP1... then I converted to .NET 4.0 and some fields refuse to load giving an error like:

System.InvalidOperationException: The table 'Tickets' does not have a column named 'Contact'.

The stack trace shows System.Web.DynamicData.MetaTable.GetColumn(String columnName) throwing the actual exception, so thinking something was changed with that function.  No idea what, however... :(

I've verified that the columns are there (I can access using Eval() and such, but DynamicControl won't find the columns.)  To make matters worse, there are several fields for which it DOES work and I can't see anything really different between the columns that do work and the ones that don't.  All of the ones that do not work are associations, but there are associations that work as well.

EDIT:  Just changed the question title... I traced through and grabbed the MetaTable itself using System.Web.DynamicData.MetaTable.GetTable(), and sure enough the MetaTable is missing the column.  I just don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out...

The Associations were using columns that were not the Primary Key.  So by setting all the columns involved on the Child table to be primary keys, it works again in .NET 4.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this? I think it might be related to a problem I'm having but I'm not sure exactly what you did there.